# Remove multicolumn line in one line latex

Tags: latex

I have the following LaTex table

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Top 5 letras menos frequentes retornadas pelo método \emph{Lossy Counter} quando se considera $e$ como $0.1, 0.01, 0.001$, Lossy($e$), comparando com as letras menos frequentes retornadas pelo método \emph{Exact Counter} - \textit{O Livro de Cesário Verde}}
\label{e_lossy}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{| *{9}{c|}}
\hline
 \backslashbox{Top 5}{Counter} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Exact} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Lossy (0.1)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Lossy (0.01)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Lossy (0.001)}\\ \hline
 1 & K & 4 & V & 340 & Y & 1 & Y & 47  \\ \hline
 2 & Y & 54 & P & 1426 & X & 72 & X & 155 \\\hline
 3 & X & 155 & L & 2091 & J & 102 & J & 208 \\ \hline
 4 & J & 28 & C & 2527 & Z & 325 & Z & 344 \\ \hline
 5 & Z & 344 & T & 2833 & F & 701 & F & 701 \\ \hline
 Nº Letras & 25 &  & 15 & . & 24 & . & 24 & . \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

[image]

In the last line, the 'Nºletras' line, I would like to only have 1 column instead of 2, per column, i.e, instead of having

```
NºLetras | 25 | .| 15 | . | 24 | . | 24 | . |
```

I would like to have

```
NºLetras | 25 | 15 | 24 | 24 |
```

Where 25 is for all exact column, 15 for all Lossy(0.01) column, etc.

I'm sorry if I didn't express the problem well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Like in your first row, you can use `\multicolumn` to merge two cells together.
- you should never use `\resizebox` for things which contain text. This will give very poor results.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Top 5 letras menos frequentes retornadas pelo método \emph{Lossy Counter} quando se considera $e$ como $0.1, 0.01, 0.001$, Lossy($e$), comparando com as letras menos frequentes retornadas pelo método \emph{Exact Counter} - \textit{O Livro de Cesário Verde}}
\label{e_lossy}
%\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{| *{9}{c|}}
\hline
 \backslashbox{Top 5}{Counter} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Exact} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Lossy (0.1)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Lossy (0.01)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Lossy (0.001)}\\ \hline
 1 & K & 4 & V & 340 & Y & 1 & Y & 47  \\ \hline
 2 & Y & 54 & P & 1426 & X & 72 & X & 155 \\\hline
 3 & X & 155 & L & 2091 & J & 102 & J & 208 \\ \hline
 4 & J & 28 & C & 2527 & Z & 325 & Z & 344 \\ \hline
 5 & Z & 344 & T & 2833 & F & 701 & F & 701 \\ \hline
 Nº Letras & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{25} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{15} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{24} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{24} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
%}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

For multiply columns, there will be `\begin{multicols}{2}`. Here, `2` means two columns in a single page.

Now to stop it, do the following:

```
\end{multicols}
This is in a single column area
\begin{multicols}{2}
```

Comment: The question is not about columns of text, it is about columns in a table.